# compare cell value to reference value and look for a partial match

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a method to compare a list of cell values to a certain reference value. If I would only need to compare the values I'd know how to achieve that. But here is the kicker: How can I look for a partial match? e.g.: the reference value should be "good". If the value of those cells would be "good" as well it should be considered a match. If the cell value is "Mr. goodcat" it should also be considered a match. My best guess would be to reference the original value to a string variable and put in some "*" if that would be possible. 
Since I am not able to post some code, I don't need you to give me the whole answer, but a point in the right direction would be very nice. Thanks in advance guys.

*edit*: I have put in my final code. A short explaination: It loops through values in Sheet2 and compares them to values in column J in Sheet 1. If it finds a (partial) match, it highlights the cell.

```
Sub CompareValues()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws1Lrow As Long
Dim ws2Lrow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim reference As String

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

ws1Lrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ws2Lrow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 1 To ws2Lrow Step 1
    ws2.Select
        Cells(i, 1).Select
        reference = ActiveCell

    ws1.Select
        For x = 2 To ws1Lrow
            k = InStr(1, Cells(x, 10), reference, vbTextCompare)
            If k > 0 Then
                Cells(x, 10).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
        Next x
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: I think you should post an examplary code anyway - just make up a fictional scenario.

Comment: So, choose 2 out of 3 :  Fast, Good, Cheap.  Go thru the list once looking for variations on each list item, or go thru the list many times(1st time look for exact match, 2nd time look for preceeding "*", 3rd time look for trailing "*", 4th time look for some phonetic match, ...), or go thru once using only a hash match...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
Dim I As Integer
I = InStr(1, "Mr. goodcat", "good", vbTextCompare)
If I > 0 Then
    ' Match
Else
    ' No Match
End
```

Here's more advanced function which allows wildcards in the middle:

```
Function PatternMatch(ByVal SearchIn As String, ByVal Pattern As String) As Boolean

    If Len(SearchIn) = 0 Or Len(Pattern) = 0 Then
        PatternMatch = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim Position As Integer
    Dim MatchFirst As Boolean
    Dim MatchLast As Boolean
    Dim Chunks() As String

    MatchFirst = (Left(Pattern, 1) <> "*")
    MatchLast = (Right(Pattern, 1) <> "*")

    Chunks = Split(Pattern, "*")
    LastChunkIndex = UBound(Chunks)

    If MatchFirst Then
        If Not (Left(SearchIn, Len(Chunks(0))) = Chunks(0)) Then
            PatternMatch = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    If MatchLast Then
        If Not (Right(SearchIn, Len(Chunks(LastChunkIndex))) = Chunks(LastChunkIndex)) Then
            PatternMatch = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    Position = 1

    For Each Chunk In Chunks
        ChunkLength = Len(Chunk)
        If ChunkLength > 0 Then
            NextPosition = InStr(Position, SearchIn, Chunk, vbTextCompare)
            If NextPosition > 0 And NextPosition >= Position Then
                Position = NextPosition + ChunkLength
            Else
                PatternMatch = False
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next Chunk

    PatternMatch = True

End Function
```