# VBA partial match

Tags: excel, vba

I've been making what started out as a basic asset tracker, but as its progressed more and more has been added.
before this I've never done anything with excel, meaning most of what i have done has been through searching, copying, and making slight changes to code found online.

Im now trying to search for a client name held on a "Database" sheet and display all assets assigned to that client on a "Reports" sheet

I have "Userform5" with a command box auto populating the name of the client as you begin typing

Client name is often referred to differently, so the official client name is loaded into the command box, however on the spreadsheet it may have been inputted as a shortened version of the name. Eg, Tarmac Trading Limited is the official name loaded into the command box, on the Database this may be input as just Tarmac or another slight variation.

i have a code that works fine, but only for exact matches, and will even disregard if a space has been entered at the end of the client name on "database"

is there a way to change the below code to search for partial matches?

```
Sub ClientSearch_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Client As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Sheets("Reports").Range("A2:aj10000").ClearContents
Client = Trim(Cmbclient.Text)
Sheets("Database").Activate

finalrow = Sheets("Database").Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To finalrow
'Function equalsIgnoreCase(str1 As String, str2 As String) As Boolean
 '   equalsIgnoreCase = LCase(str1) = LCase(str2)
'End Function


If LCase(Sheets("Database").Cells(i, 4)) = LCase(Client) Then


Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 50)).Copy
Sheets("Reports").Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If

Next i

Sheets("Reports").Activate

Range("A:AZ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("B:B,D:D,E:E,F:F,G:G,H:H,I:I,J:J,K:K,L:L,M:M,N:N,Q:Q,AB:AB,AF:AF,AG:AG,AH:AH,AI:AI,AJ:AJ").EntireColumn.Hidden = False


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Unload UserForm5

End Sub
```

Comment: Consider using `RANGE.FIND()` and setting the `LookAt` argument to `xlPart` to determineif there is a match or if it `Is Nothing`. Or you might consider using the `Like` keyword in place of `=` and applying `*` as a wildcard: `Like "Tarmac*" Or Like "*Tarmac*"`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find

Comment: Also, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192248/compare-cell-value-to-reference-value-and-look-for-a-partial-match

Answer (score 0):

Replace

If LCase(Sheets("Database").Cells(i, 4)) = LCase(Client) Then

with

If LCase(Sheets("Database").Cells(i, 4)) = LCase(Client) Or InStr(LCase(Client), LCase(Sheets("DataBase"), Cells(i, 4))) > 0 Then